# Spring Data Neo4j 4 - How to fetch parent of many to many entities correctly?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I have this problem when using findByIngredientId on pairing class I can't get ingredient (null) in the pairing result. But on debug mode the ingredient got fetched. What is the right way to fetch ingredient? 
I tried using loadAllByProperty but its not working. It show the error below. 
Is this the right way to fetch the parent node?

```
com.food.model.neo.Ingredient["pairings"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.food.model.neo.Pairing["first"]->com.food.model.neo.Ingredient["pairings"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.food.model.neo.Pairing["first"]->com.food.model.neo.Ingredient["pairings"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.food.model.neo.Pairing["first"]->com.food.model.neo.Ingredient["pairings"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.food.model.neo.Pairing["first"]->com.food.model.neo.Ingredient["pairings"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.food.model.neo.Pairing["first"]->com.food.model.neo.Ingredient["pairings"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.food.model.neo.Pairing["first"]->com.food.model.neo.Ingredient["pairings"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.food.model.neo.Pairing["first"]->com.food.model.neo.Ingredient["pairings"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.food.model.neo.Pairing["first"]->com.food.model.neo.Ingredient["pairings"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.food.model.neo.Pairing["first"]->com.food.model.neo.Ingredient["pairings"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.food.model.neo.Pairing["first"]->com.food.model.neo.Ingredient["pairings"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.food.model.neo.Pairing["first"]->com.food.model.neo.Ingredient["pairings"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.food.model.neo.Pairing["first"]->com.food.model.neo.Ingredient["pairings"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.food.model.neo.Pairing["first"]->com.food.model.neo.Ingredient["pairings"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.food.model.neo.Pairing["first"]-
```

And this is my classes:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Ingredient {

    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @Relationship(type = "HAS_CATEGORY", direction = "OUTGOING")
    private Category category;

    @Relationship(type = "PAIRS_WITH", direction = "UNDIRECTED")
    private Set<Pairing> pairings = new HashSet<>();
}

@NodeEntity
public class Category {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}

@RelationshipEntity(type = "PAIRS_WITH")
public class Pairing {

    Long id;

    @StartNode
    private Ingredient first;
    @EndNode
    private Ingredient second;

    private String affinity;
}
```

This is my Controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foodStory", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView foodStory() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("home");

    categoryRepository.deleteAll();
    ingredientRepository.deleteAll();
    pairingRepository.deleteAll();

    //Set up the categories
    Category meat = new Category("Meat");
    Category veg = new Category("Vegetable");
    categoryRepository.save(meat);
    categoryRepository.save(veg);

    //Set up two ingredients
    Ingredient chicken = new Ingredient("Chicken");
    chicken.setCategory(meat);
    ingredientRepository.save(chicken);

    Ingredient carrot = new Ingredient("Carrot");
    carrot.setCategory(veg);
    ingredientRepository.save(carrot);


    //Pair them
    Pairing pairing = new Pairing();
    pairing.setFirst(chicken);
    pairing.setSecond(carrot);
    pairing.setAffinity("Delicious");
    pairingRepository.save(pairing);

    Ingredient carrotIngredient = session.loadByProperty(Ingredient.class, "name", "Carrot");
    List<Pairing> pairingList = (List<Pairing>) session.loadAllByProperty(Pairing.class, "second", carrotIngredient);
    //Check the data in pairingList and the result :
    //expect to happens : pairings.first != null
    //what happens : pairings.first = null
    System.out.println("Done");
return model;
}
```

When I try to look at my pairingList data, pairings.first return null data.

Comment: Could you please add some comments to your sample above that specifies a) What you're expecting to happen b) What is actually happening

Comment: I already update the question and add some comment. thank you